# If session exists have access to website while maintenance_mode set to true

Tags: codeigniter

When I set my config_maintenance to True  on my config page. In **core/Catalog_Controller.php** which is front end then it redirects to maintenance page

**Question:** How can I make it so if a `$admin_userdata['user_id']` exists in session then will be able to access
website while config_maintenance set to true.

```
<?php

class Catalog_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $admin_userdata = $this->session->userdata('admin');

        // $admin_userdata['user_id'];

        if (config_item('config_maintenance') == TRUE) {
            redirect('catalog/common/maintenance');
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if(!empty($admin_userdata)){ // redirect to file }else{ if (config_item('config_maintenance') == TRUE) {
            redirect('catalog/common/maintenance');
        }  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But before that ensure that you have the session library included.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Get Session Data:

```
if($this->session->userdata('admin')){
    if (config_item('config_maintenance') == TRUE) {
            redirect('catalog/common/maintenance');
        } 
}else{
    // do something when doesn't exist
}
```